# How to use unity container registered Named Type in ServiceStack Requesthandler

Tags: c#, web-services, servicestack, unity-container, ioc-container

I am using ServiceStack (5.12.0) in my ASP.NET service along with Unity Container.
I am registering instances of same type  as follows

```
public static IUnityContainer Create()
{
    container.RegisterType<ITest, Clock1>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
    container.RegisterType<ITest, TestClock>("TestClock", new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
}
```

This is how I am injecting instance in servicestack handler

```
    public class testRequestHandlers: Service
    {
        private readonly ITest _clock;
        public testRequestHandlers( ITest clock)    
        {           
            this._clock = clock;
        }
   }
```

I want to use "TestClock" in other handler, but each time it gives instance of Clock1 and I
could not able to figure out how to do it.I have tried following

```
public class test2RequestHandlers : Service
{
        private readonly ITest _clock;

        public test2RequestHandlers([Dependency("TestClock")] ITest clock)
        {
            this._clock = clock;
        }
}
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Third Party IOC's provide the dependencies to inject but they don't handle construction of Service classes so Unity's attributes have no effect.

As you can only have a single registration for a given type (e.g. `ITest`) you would typically register dependencies against different types to specify which dependency to use, e.g:

```cs
container.RegisterType<TestClock>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
```

```cs
public class Test2RequestHandlers : Service
{
    private readonly ITest clock;

    public Test2RequestHandlers(TestClock clock)
    {
        this.clock = clock;
    }
}
```

Alternatively you can resolve named dependencies from ServiceStack's IOC within your Service implementation with:

```cs
this.clock = HostContext.Container.ResolveNamed<ITest>("TestClock");
```